# Нужна помощь в реализации комментариев на Django

Tags: python, django

Если быть точнее, нужно переписать рабочую функцию на класс DetailView или же предложить лучшую реализацию. И было бы здорово получить решение привязки Юзера к комментарию, так как в моем случае приходиться выбирать из всех существующих. Заранее спасибо!

Функция:

```
def product_detail(request, pk):
    template_name = 'main/product_detail.html'
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    comments = product.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.product = product
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'product': product,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'form': form})
```

Модель:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    username = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.username)
```

Форма:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('username', 'body')
```

Шаблон:

```
<!-- comments -->
        <h2>{{ comments.count }} comments</h2>
              <hr>
 {% for comment in comments %}
            <p>{{ comment.body | linebreaks }}</p>
            <small class="text-muted">Posted by <b>{{ comment.username }}</b> on {{ comment.created_on }}</small><br><br>
{% endfor %}
            <hr>


        {% if new_comment %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          Your comment is awaiting moderation
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
        <form action="." method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
          {{ form.as_p }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Leave a Review</button>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то привязать юзера к модели cледует так:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

А потом перед тем как будешь сохранять форму:

```
 form.user = request.user
 form.save()
```

А по поводу переписать функцию на класс можешь взять этот пример.

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = DetailForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Write Your Logic here

            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = DetailForm
            return self.render_to_response(context=context)

        else:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = form
            return self.render_to_response( context=context)
```